# Adobe Photoshop - change canvas ratio in repeatable (scriptable) manner without cropping/resizing photo, and colour the increased border

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I state the purpose of my question as well as my question then hopefully this will be clear and why the other rather large range of answers on a similar topic aren't helpful.

Instagram uses square images in it's list, so I want to create a script to go into a folder of images and turn all of them into square images. But I don't want distortion or cropping. What I want is for the image to remain in the middle and the canvas to grow.  Then any area that was added will be coloured either white or black.

I can do this manually but using the crop tool, telling it to be a square (ratio 1:1) and then dragging left to the edge and the right to it's edge.
Or using Canvas resize, and copying the largest size (depends if image is portrait or landscape) and putting that into the smaller size. Then using flood fill to colour the transparent bars that are created.

Before ->

[image: Non square image]

After ->

[image: Square Image]

So how can I automate this process? Seems like there are human elements in my process that I can't automate and I guess there must be a way. I have the latest photoshop (also Lightroom if it can do it?).

Comment: Why arent you using imagemagick for this? No there is no human intervention needed.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are all the images the exact same dimensions to begin with? If so, it could be done with an Action, and File > Automate > Batch.

Comment: Thanks @joojaa I've never heard of imagemagick. I'll check it out.

Comment: @BillyKerr nope they are all different. landscape/portrait and a range of ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your images are flattened, you can record an action like this:

- Right-click the *Background* layer and select *Duplicate Layer*.
- Double-click the *Background* layer to unlock it and select it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to start transforming the selected layer. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, rotate the layer 90 degrees and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit the transformation.
- Perform *Image > Reveal All* to make the canvas a square.
- Press <kbd>D</kbd> to reset the background and foreground colors.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to fill the selected layer with black.
- Perform *Layer > Flatten Image* to flatten the image.

Comment: That's a clever trick!  +1!!!!!

Comment: Wow - that's some magic knowledge right there!!

Awesome and perfectly scriptable.

Comment: @delp - but you don't need to script this. The Action alone would suffice. Just apply it using File > Automate > Batch.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yeah that's what I'm meaning. Record the action then can apply that to every image.  I was thinking of it like a script, but I think photoshop calls them actions. 
Just bad terminology from me.

Comment: @delp - yeah, Photoshop has Actions, but you can also use scripts.  Actions are like recording a macro. Scripts have to be manually programmed using JavaScript, VB Script, AppleScript etc,

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm very new to Photoshop. Didn't even think about being able to use JS to create a script for it. I'm used to using JS so I may well look into that, just out of curiosity :)

Comment: @delp, you could make a more elegant solution using JavaScript. I just like using actions if I can. Scripting often consumes time if there's some quirky little detail I'm not getting right. I might add a script solution later. But I don't like script only answers so I would need to explain what's going on.

Comment: @delp There's also a ScriptListener plugin which you can use to get you started. I'm no programmer, but I've used it before, then hacked the code it generated for my needs.